# Best way to render many cubes with static position but dynamic visibility/opacity?

Tags: three.js

I want to render a lot of simple lambert-like cubes. I tried individually adding meshes to the scene, but that is very slow.

So I merged their geometries. This is faster, but it's still slow when every cube has its own material. I wanted to use the material visibility to toggle the drawing of each cube. I would use vertexcolors, but that only controls the color and not the opacity/visibility.

I really just need two materials for visible/invisible. But the materialIndex of a face can't be changed after creation I think? So that didn't work.

I tried a shaderMaterial, which is fast! But to get a lambert-like look I would need to program that shader myself. That seems much too complicated for such a simple task.

Ideas? would it be faster to use a single material for every cube but fake visibility by moving it away?

Comment: since you only want to use visibility as on or off, instead of using the material use the mesh.visible attribute.

Comment: Hmm but then I would need to add every cube as its own mesh to the scene or as a child of a "group". Doing that with let's say 1000 cubes was slow last time I checked, no?

Comment: well it depends on how much was your gain when merging. but generally state changes (i.e. material) is more expensive. you will have to try and see.

Comment: I have a scene with 1000+ cubes with MeshPhongMaterials, a plane, skybox, ambient-, directional- and spotlight for shadows and it still runs smoothly in chrome. Can you show us your code? It would be easier to optimize it.

Comment: BTW: To create an own shader with a lambert-like look isn't that difficult. I don't the syntax from OpenGL but you could google 'diffuse light opengl' or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

sorry I can't comment because I don't have enough rep...

one way would be to use a buffergeometry, add an opacity flag as attribute, copy the original lambert shader and instead of the opacity value in the shader which is a uniform replace it with your attribute, that should work.